# JEditorPane.scrollToReference(String) not working

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

So I have a desktop app that I'm writing and I would like to add some help documentation.  It utilizes a cardLayout so I have created another JPanel "card" that contains a JScrollPane which contains a JEditorPane.  Everything displays fine, but I am unable to get the hyperlinks (which are links to anchors on the same page) to work as they do when I open the help.html file up in my browser.  Here is my [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/):

```
package com.example.test;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

class myClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("JEditorPane Test");

        String html=null;
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/test/help.html")));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line);
            html = sb.toString();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
            System.out.println(sw.toString());
            html = "<html><font id=\"TOC\" size=\"+2\"><b>404 Error:</b></font><br/><br/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<u>/com/swbc/datamasking/help.html</u> <b>not found.</b><br/><br/>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<font size=\"-1\"><i>Press ESC key to continue.</i></font></html>";
        }
        JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
        ep.setContentType("text/html");
        ep.setText(text);
        ep.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ep);
        f.add(sp);
        f.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);

        ep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        @Override public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent pE) {
            if (HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED == pE.getEventType()) {
            String desc = pE.getDescription();
            if (desc == null || !desc.startsWith("#")) return;
            desc = desc.substring(1);
            ep.scrollToReference(desc);
            }
        }
        });

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here are the redacted contents of the "help.html" file that it is trying to load (tags and attributes) are unedited:

```
<html><body>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;">
        <a href="#Intro" id="TOP">Help File Intro</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#Topic1">Topic #1</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#Topic2">Topic #2</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#Topic3">Topic #3</a><br/><br/>
        &emsp;&emsp;<a href="#Topic3a">Topic #3a</a><br/><br/>
        &emsp;&emsp;<a href="#Topic3b">Topic #3b</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#Topic4">Topic #4</a><br/><br/>
        <a href="#Close">Closing</a><br/><br/>
    </font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <HR width="80%" size="2" color="black">
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Intro" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Help File Intro</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic1" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #1</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic2" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #2</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic3" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #3</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic3a" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #3a</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic3b" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #3b</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Topic4" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Topic #4</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Close" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">In Conclusion</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a maximus elit. Donec tincidunt semper lectus vel scelerisque. Vivamus in sapien sit amet nisi maximus tincidunt nec et quam. Vivamus euismod posuere neque, at scelerisque mi iaculis ac. Quisque a enim id lorem sodales consequat. Vestibulum bibendum metus sagittis, suscipit arcu ac, faucibus mauris. Ut odio elit, sollicitudin in nisl tristique, semper suscipit purus. Duis mollis lectus non ex tincidunt, quis aliquam enim dapibus. Praesent tincidunt libero ac eros rutrum.</font>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <a size="+1" id="Tips" style="word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:bold;" href="#TOP" title="Click here to return to questions">Top Secret Hints & Tips (shhhh!)</a><br/><br/>
    <font style="word-wrap:break-word">Sorry no secrets here.<br/><br/><i>Check back later for some secret tips.</i></font><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

Yes, yes, I know; it's ugly, doesn't use CSS, blah, blah, etc. I didn't write it, a colleague that is no longer around wrote it.  I plan to rewrite it, but I need to show that this is a workable solution before I do.  If it isn't I'll be writing a bunch of text boxes. :-/

Comment: Java Swing has a [JavaHelp](https://javahelp.java.net/) API which might help solve the problem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the link to a good resource I hadn't come across before.  Helped me to discover what my issue was - see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that there was absolutely nothing wrong with the java code.  Other than that the default parser in the JEditorPane HTMLEditorKit is not as flexible as most of today's browsers.  The HTML had to be modified to change the id attribute to a name attribute then everything worked as billed.

```
<a href="#Intro" id="TOP">
```

transformed to:

```
<a href="#Intro" name="TOP">
```

Comment: *"JEditorPane HTMLEditorKit is not as flexible as most of today's browsers"* - Well considering it was created back in the late 90's, that's not all that surprising :P